# Difference between "while" and "until" in Bash

Tags: bash, while-loop

What is the real difference between while and until ?

I'd like to know if it's possible to do an increasingly loop with "until" and a descending loop with while.

Because I saw that if I do this

```
COUNTER=0
     while [ $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do
         echo The counter is $COUNTER
         let COUNTER+=1 
     done
```

and this

```
COUNTER=20
     until [ $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do
         echo COUNTER $COUNTER
         let COUNTER-=1
     done
```

they work well.

But if I do the opposite, for example:

```
COUNTER=20
     while [ $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do
         echo COUNTER $COUNTER
         let COUNTER-=1
     done
```

the script doesn't end.

Does this means that we cannot do a reverse loop with a while in bash?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`while` runs the loop *while* the condition is true.  `until` runs the loop *until* the condition is true (i.e. *while* the condition is false).

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs.

Comment: Has anyone ever told you not to use the words you're defining in the definition? :)

Comment: to be jovial, `while` is a placeholder and so could be any combination of any charset, like `wh!13`  ;-O

Answer (score 24):

**While Loop** executes the block of code (enclosed in **do...done**) when the condition is *true* and keeps executing that till the condition becomes *false*. Once the condition becomes *false*, the while loop is terminated.

**Until Loop** executes the block of code (enclosed in **do...done**) when the condition is *false* and keep executing that till the condition becomes *true*. Once the condition becomes *true*, the until loop is terminated.

```
COUNTER=20
while [ $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do
    echo COUNTER $COUNTER
    let COUNTER-=1
done
```

On the very first occasion, the condition mentioned in while, i.e. ***[ $COUNTER -lt 10 ]***, holds false, so the block of code inside the while loop will not run at all.

Answer (score 12):

They are opposite:

```
bool b;
while(b) = until(!b)
```

Answer (score 7):

Basically, while & until loops will only execute if the initial condition is met, think of while loops while,  if the current condition is met only then will it work. However, until loops will wait until the condition is met. For example. The following will work because 5 is less than 10, the body of the loops increments the value until is exactly ten it will quit.

```
index=5
until [ $index -gt 10 ]
do
  echo $index
  let index+=1
done
```

This example would not work, because 5 is not initially greater than 10, only during the loop it becomes greater.

```
index=5
while [ $index -gt 10 ]
do
  echo $index
  let index+=1
done
```

Comment: Very precisely explained! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Btw:

```
COUNTER=20
while [ $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do
    echo COUNTER $COUNTER
    let COUNTER-=1
done
```

This will not execute forever. Counter (20) is not less than 10 during the first evaluation of the loop condition so it will terminate immediately.